# Rails: create lots of almost-duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write a method that creates a bunch of almost-duplicate records, just with one or two parameters changed. I'll make a form to control those parameters, I'm just wondering about how best to write the method, and where do keep it.

Presently in my `document.rb` I've written this:

```
def self.publish(brand, components, template)
  brand.users.each do |user|
    Document.create(:component_ids => components, :message => 'Message.', :template_id => template.id, :user_id => user.id)
  end
end
```

It doesn't feel right though. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fine if your security model allows all these fields to be bulk assignable by mention in `attr_accessible` in the model.   If it doesn't then you're better off using the block form of `create`.  Also, if Document, Template and User are ActiveRecord instances, you should let Rails manage the details of ids.

```
def self.publish(brand, components, template)
  brand.users.each do |user|
    Document.create do |doc|
      doc.component_ids = components, 
      doc.message 'Message.', 
      doc.template = template, 
      doc.user = user
    end
  end
end
```

One final note is that `component_ids` must be serialized to store a list.  This is probably a flaw in your model design.  The better way is (probably) to specify Component `belongs_to` User and also User `has_many` Components.  I.e. Component contains a foreign key to User.  If it's necessary for a Component to belong also to many users, then you'll need either `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many ... through`.  The [Rails guide on relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) describes all this in more detail.

With the right relations set up, the code will become:

```
def self.publish(brand, components, template)
  brand.users.each do |user|
    Document.create do |doc|
      doc.components = components,  # Components is now a list of active records.
      doc.message 'Message.', 
      doc.template = template, 
      doc.user = user
    end
  end
end
```

The resulting SQL will get all the foreign keys and (if necessary) relation tables filled in correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As far as accessing form parameters goes, it seems like I should call that method from a controller action while saving the params from the form too. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @emm Certainly having the function in a model and calling it from a controller makes sense.  I'm not sure what you mean by "saving the params from the form".

Comment: Your updated answer makes a lot of sense. By "params from the form" I meant that I want that method to combine some `params[:document]` from a form while use the `publish(brand, components, template)` options set in the controller.

Comment: @emm Okay.  Good.  The basic rule is to never give `attr_accessible` on any field that must be protected from setting by a form field _in any part of the system whatsoever_.  Note in Rails 4 this problem is fixed by moving the accessibility permissions to controllers and the `params` class itself.